# Referencing dictionaries in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have two codes, where a dictionary is a member of another one. In the first code, dictionary 'a' is referenced in dictionary 'b' using {}:

```
a = {'one': [1, 1]}
b = {'member': a}
print b
a = {'one': [2, 2]}
print b
```

In the second code, dictionary 'a' is referenced in dictionary 'b' using []:

```
a = {}
a['one'] = [1, 1]
b = {}
b['member'] = a
print b
a['one'] = [2, 2]
print b
```

Can anybody explain to me why, the second print b in the first code returns:

```
{'member': {'one': [1, 1]}}
```

whereas in the second code the result for the same print is:

```
{'member': {'one': [2, 2]}}
```

Sincerely,
Fran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code,

```
a = {'one': [2, 2]}
```

points the name `a` to a brand new dictionary, so it no longer points to the dictionary stored in `b` (which is unchanged). In the second,

```
a['one'] = [2, 2]
```

updates the existing dictionary referenced by `a`, which is referenced within `b` too. This difference is not related to the creation of `b`, as

```
b = {}
b['member'] = a
```

and

```
b = {'member': a}
```

give exactly the same result.